# Unexpected behaviour when using Angular Promise.all without catch method

Tags: angular, promise

I use Angular's `Promise.all()` method. Because the error handling happens in the service, I don't need the `.catch()` method in the component. But when I leave it - like in the example - the `.then()` method gets executed even if one of the promises get rejected. I don't understand why that is happening.

Code example:

```
const promises = [promise1, promise2];
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(suc => {
    // gets executed in error case
    this.result1= suc[0];
    this.result2= suc[1];
  });
```

Comment: what do you mean by `promises fail`?

Comment: Can't help without seeing the logic for `promise1` and `promise2`, but if you `catch` in the service, then the promise didn't fail.

Comment: @Maximus I meant if the promise get rejected.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen But the catch method in the component is executed when I add it and one of the promises get rejected.

Comment: Catching and then rejecting is quite similar to not catching at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving the error handling from the service to the component. Because when you catch an error in the service, it doesn't get properly passed to the component.